# Shrink parent to fit children during jQuery animate width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a **relative** positioned parent with **absolute** positioned images inside it having width:100% .

I set the initial height of parent using jquery equal to the images aspect ratio. The problem is that another animations in the page, shrinks the div. **during the shrinkage** I want to fit the parent to children image.

How can I maintain the aspect ratio of parent during the animation? (perhaps something like window resize listener?) Please note that this shrinkage is a sample animation. I have a complex animation in real and so I am looking for a general solution in every moments not for this sample target 200px width.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var width=$("#wrapper").width();
 $("#wrapper").height(width*0.33);
  
  
  $("#shrink").click(function(){
    $("#wrapper").animate({"width":"200px"},3000)
  })
})
```

```css
#wrapper{
  position:relative;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid #444444;
}

.child{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  }

#shrink{cursor:pointer}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="shrink">Click here to shrink</a>
<br><br>
<div id="wrapper">
  <img class="child" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I found the general solution using jQuery **step** function. step is an option in jQuery animate which is triggered in every step of animation. So I can write a resize function and call it on every step.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 resizeWrapper();
  
  
  $("#shrink").click(function(){
    $("#wrapper").animate({"width":"200px"},{duration:3000,step:function(){resizeWrapper()}})
  })
})

function resizeWrapper(){
 var width=$("#wrapper").width();
 $("#wrapper").height(width*0.33);

}
```

```css
#wrapper{
  position:relative;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid #444444;
}

.child{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  }

#shrink{cursor:pointer}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="shrink">Click here to shrink</a>
<br><br>
<div id="wrapper">
  <img class="child" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
</div>
```

I  also found [detect resize](https://github.com/sdecima/javascript-detect-element-resize) but It did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variable to store the scaling factor of the `width` (i.e `newWidth / width`), then multiply the `height` by this factor to get the new `height`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var width = $("#wrapper").width();
  $("#wrapper").height(width * 0.33);

  var newWidth = 200;
  var scalingFactor = newWidth / width;
  var height = $("#wrapper").height();

  $("#shrink").click(function() {
    $("#wrapper").animate({
      "width": newWidth + "px",
      "height" : height * scalingFactor + "px"
    }, 3000)
  })
})
```

```css
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #444444;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
#shrink {
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="shrink">Click here to shrink</a>
<br>
<br>
<div id="wrapper">
  <img class="child" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer works just for an exact target width where I have no Idea about the final width. This shrinking button is a sample, I have a complex animation with no idea about the width during the animation. I upvoted your answer but I have to wait more for a general solution.

Comment: You're welcome! I just tried to solve the problem with the snippet in your code. if you have no Idea about the final width, then that's a different story. Can you post your complete code?! or a minified version of it?!

Comment: Thanks again. I am sorry that the question as not clear enough. I found a general solution and posted it as a new answer.